# How many skills/items/upgrades can I buy in a single playthrough?

Tags: dishonored

I just started *Dishonored* last night and I was wondering, just how far can I get in the tech tree in a single playthrough? Can I buy everything? Are there branches that cut each other off or simply not enough coin to buy it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible with upgrades, but it's not necessarily a huge amount of fun spending a lot of time searching for coin loot. Runes, definitely not but you can get at least half. It's worth doing two playthroughs anyway (one ghosting, one hyperviolent vengeance spree).

Answer (score 1):

I was able, by being thorough in my loot collecting, to have more than enough coin to buy all the upgrades that I had available after collecting all the blueprints I found. Although you won't actually need to buy all the upgrades if you stick to one play style through the entire game.

Comment: This covers gadget upgrades, but not powers, which require runes, of which I don't think there are enough.